# Trying to find an example of "foolproof" oauth architecture with refresh tokens

Tags: angular, authentication, oauth, jwt

I'm in the process of setting up oauth with refresh tokens for my angular app and I have a list of requirements:

- Refresh the token periodically (when 5% of the time remains for example)
- Handle loss of connectivity (refresh when connected again)
- Handle multiple tabs in the browser (all trying to refresh the same token at the same time, sign out in another tab, etc)
- Pause/retry HTTP requests when the token is invalid/refreshed

At the moment I'm trying to build the whole refresh logic myself, but I keep running into corner cases that complicate the process a lot. For example multiple tabs. One tab refreshes the token and gets a new one. Before the other tab picks up on this, it tries to refresh the old token (with a now invalid refresh token) and the refresh fails.

I feel that there must be tons of others who's had the same requirements as me, and that there must be examples/libraries/open source projects with exactly this? Does anyone know of any resources that could help me?

Comment: I'd suggest to restate the question to not focus on asking for resources, because this kind of questions is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve with current oauth attempt (https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api can be used for serverless example) can help to keep it on topic, too. Since there's a finite amount of possible good answers, the question has its chance.

Answer (score 2):

We do exactly that, but I doubt that there are any libraries to use for the whole setup, as this involved both front-end and backend and you will likely have different frameworks for each and possibly different programming languages.

In short, the solution we applied is:

- After login, the client is issued an Access Token and Refresh Token
- The Refresh Token is presented to the client as a HTTPS only cookie
- The Access Token is stored by the client in local storage
- A sync process ensures Access Tokens are synced across multiple clients in tabs
- When Access Token has expired, the 401 requests are intercepted and a new Access Token is requested using the Refresh Token
- The failed 401 request is automatically retried ()
- When new Access Tokens are obtained by one of the tabs, the other clients get and use the new Access Token via the sync process

It's a lot of pieces for the puzzle, but not that hard to set up once you're clear on what you're doing and how you want it to work. As with everything, there's of course plenty of room for modifications or improvements based on your own specific use case and security requirements.

Comment: How does this not fail, if multiple tabs try to ask with the expired access token? They should both get a 401 and both try to use the refresh token. One of them wins the 'race', the other makes a request with a now obsolete refresh token and kills the session (or doesn't he?)

Comment: Good point @DánielSomogyi, I think we may have run into this issue a few times actually since this was implemented. Generally though, only one of the tabs should be active at any given time, and it's unlikely that there will be active requests at the exact same time in both tabs. So one will refresh, and then the other tab will update itself.